# Сохранение основных свойств в WinForm'е

Tags: c#, winforms

Как можно сохранить, к примеру, цвет FORM'ы, шрифт букв на BUTTON'e, LABEL'е при закрытии программы(.exe) и новом открытии. Как это все экспортировать и заново считать и задать.
При возможности дайте, пожалуйста, конкретные примеры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открываем свойство проекта и идем на вкладку "Параметры".

1. Заводим к примеру сеттинг Form1Color.
2. Задаем его тип System.Drawing.Color
3. Заводим обработчик события FormClosed в котором указываем что в него записать

   ```
   private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
   {
       ...
       Settings.Default.Form1Color = this.BackColor;
       ...
       Settings.Default.Save();
   }
   ```
4. Заводим обработчик события Load, в котором указываем, что из сеттинга надо прочитать

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ...
       this.BackColor = Settings.Default.Form1Color;
       ...
   }
   ```

с другими свойствами полностью аналогично

Comment: ваш ответ весьма интересен,но не могли бы вы описать поподробнее(а именно код в сеттинге)
заранее благодарен...!

Comment: э... Какая именно часть затруднительна для понимания? Вроде все достаточно просто - каждый параметр приложения, заведенный в свойствах, создает поле класса Properties.Settings.Default.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ товарища renegator не самый оптимальный.

Лучше всего использовать свойство `ApplicationSettings`. В редакторе свойств любого контрола выбираете `(ApplicationSettings)->(PropertyBinding)`, нажимаете на кнопку. В появившемся диалоге выбираете нужное свойство и в выпадающем списке выбираете New. В появившемся диалоге задаёте имя настройки, значение по умолчанию, `Scope` оставляете `User`.