# Сохранение свойств Button'ов WinForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

В приложении программно создаются Button'ы, и мне нужно чтоб после нажатия кнопки btnSave свойства (размер, положение, тег) созданного Button'а сохранялись. И при следующем запуске приложения все созданные ранее Button'ы были на форме. Проблема заключается в том что количество Button'ов заранее не известно!

- Должна быть возможность удаления ранее созданных Button'ов (не обязательно)

Напишите, пожалуйста, синтаксис как сохранять свойства кнопок.

Comment: Опишите задачу подробнее. Пока проблемы не вижу, сохраняем в файл нужные параметры контролов. При загрузке формы читаем из файла параметры добавляемых контролов. Но я полагаю что к ним и обработчики нужны, и еще что-то. Только ли Button-ы могут добавляться? Что уже пробовали в коде?

Comment: @rdorn мне нужен синтаксис, как сохранить размер к примеру, а как создать файл изменить его и т.п. я знаю

Comment: Button-ы добавляются в отдельный контейнер или куда попало?

Comment: _"как сохранять свойства кнопок"_ -- надо сохранять все свойства (их много) или только определенные?

Comment: @Stack для начала Tag, размер,и позицию, остальные необязательны

Comment: Вы не должны сохранять View, никогда. То, что сохраняется — это модель. Соответственно протяните нужные свойства в модель, и сериализуйте модель, как обычно.

Comment: @VladD Ну хочется человеку... лучше один раз сделать ошибку, и переделать весь проект в итоге, но научиться, хотя в продакшн такое нельзя конечно

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Произвольный Tag сохранить в файл нельзя, он должен быть в той или иной форме сериализуемым.

Comment: @rdorn: Ну разве что :) В конце-концов, надо от чего-то отталкиваться в проекте.

Comment: @VladD почему произвольный я его ввожу переменной вручную + он сохраняется в базе данных. К тому же проект на оценку а не на продажу, так что говно код подходит

Comment: @Vyacheslav практический совет - даже на оценку говнокод не стоит, слишком быстро к нему привыкание возникает, отвыкать потом долго

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Смотря на чью оценку. Если на оценку потенциального работодателя, я бы за говнокод выгонял с интервью и не тратил своего времени.

Comment: @VladD да я студент, мне сдать практику и забыть, я больше хочу на веб-разработчика, так что привыкание к говнокоду в c# не особо страшное

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Ну, извините. У нас тут не сервис «пишем говнокод для студентов». Я могу рассказать, как писать правильно тем, кто реально хочет научиться. А писать код за тех, кто не хочет научиться — не-а.

Answer (score 1):

**Не для практического применения!!!**
Вариант решения "В лоб", без претензий на оптимальность и соответствие каким либо шаблонам. Левый клик по форме создает кнопку в случайном месте, клик по кнопке, удаляет ее, правый клик по форме, восстанавливает все поставленные ранее кнопки. Для сохранения в файл `List<ButtonParams> bps` любым сериализатором, для восстановления - десериализовать тем же способом. Не стал добавлять сериализацию, т.к. она подробно и с примерами описана в MSDN.

Решение не будет работать в общем случае, т.к. свойство `Button.Tag` имеет тип `Object`, следовательно может содержать объект не поддерживающий сериализацию.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseClick += Form1_MouseClick;
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class ButtonParams
    {
        public Size BSize { get; set; }
        public Point Location { get; set; }
        public object Tag { get; set; }
    }

    List<ButtonParams> bps = new List<ButtonParams>();

    private void CreateButton()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        ButtonParams bp = new ButtonParams();
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = bps.Count.ToString();
        bp.Tag = b.Tag = "B";
        bp.BSize = b.Size = new Size(40, 40);
        bp.Location = b.Location = new Point(rnd.Next(this.ClientSize.Width - b.Width), rnd.Next(this.ClientSize.Height - b.Height));
        b.Click += new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs e) => { this.Controls.Remove(sender as Button); });
        this.Controls.Add(b);
        this.bps.Add(bp);
    }

    private void RestoreButtons()
    {
        foreach (ButtonParams bp in this.bps)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = "B";
            b.Tag = bp.Tag;
            b.Size = bp.BSize;
            b.Location = bp.Location;
            b.Click += new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs e) => { this.Controls.Remove(sender as Button); });
            this.Controls.Add(b);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            CreateButton();
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            RestoreButtons();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: тоесть просто сохранить значение btn.Size (например) в файл txt нельзя?

Comment: @Vyacheslav можно как угодно. класс для удобства добавлен, иначе много лапши в коде получается

Comment: @Vyacheslav только тогда уж не Size а Width и Heigth, ну и X и Y для Location

Comment: @Vyacheslav вот еще родственный вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/146744/198316, думаю будет полезен на будущее.